# Garage gable fan through truss

Tags: walls, garage, ventilation, exhaust-fan, truss

I'm looking to install a ventilation fan in my garage. I want to install it in the middle (mainly for looks) rather than having it offset to one side or the other. Am I OK to cut through the middle 2x4s shown in the picture below?

[image]

I saw [Garage gable fan proper installation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/142086/garage-gable-fan-proper-installation) where one person said this was possible, but it looks like this truss is slightly different. If I do go this route, would it be worth framing the vent fan with new 2x4s?

Comment: I do not think it wise to cut truss members. I would mount the fan off center and consider it an interesting design element.

Comment: get two fans if you crave symmetry